# Dynamically generate Class-Constructor out of String

Tags: c++, destructor

In my information-model there are more then 400 data types, which are named like this: `AutomationDomainType`. The types (constructor and members) are generated out of a modeller, but unfortunately there is no destructor generated. So I have to implement their destructors and call them in my main function:

```
void deleteObjectTypeUA(OpcUa_UInt16 ObjID, OpcUa_UInt16 NsIdx)
{

if (ObjID == PrefixId_AutomationDomainType)
    {
        NodeManagerRoot* pNodeManagerRoot = NodeManagerRoot::CreateRootNodeManager();
        auto dummyTypeInstance = new NamespacePrefix::AutomationDomainTypeBase(UaNodeId(PrefixId_AutomationDomainType, 2),
            UaString("Dummy_AutomationDomainType"), 2, pNodeManagerRoot);
        dummyTypeInstance->~AutomationDomainTypeBase();
        delete dummyTypeInstance;
    }
```

I have to manually implement the destructors in the data-type `.cpp`s, but in my `deleteType` function I don't want to make 400 `if else` conditions to create a `DummyObject`, and after that the destructor (I create the `dummyobject` in order to call the destructor of the Class, not a good implementation but it works and isn't really the topic ;) )

A bit more insight: in my information model there are

1. a DataType-Object, and
2. instance-Objects of that type.

In the destructors I want to delete all instances of that type (they are tagged in a list). This all happens in the specific `datatype.cpp` file though. The `DummyObject` is only created in order to call the destructor (to delete the instances)

is there a possibility in c++ with some magic to generate this 2 lines in the snippet with the information of the `ObjID`?

```
auto dummyTypeInstance = new NamespacePrefix::AutomationDomainTypeBase(UaNodeId(NamespacePrefixId_AutomationDomainType, 2),
            UaString("Dummy_AutomationDomainType"), 2, pNodeManagerRoot);

// ...

dummyTypeInstance->~AutomationDomainTypeBase();
```

I don't want to use a script to generate the code (it would be too long).

Comment: Why do you have to call the destructors explicitly? Especially if oyu delete the instance in the next line anyways...

Comment: Good news. You don't have to call `destructor` yourself. When you call `delete dummyTypeInstance;` the framework will call it automaticaly (destructor of type that your variable has). If your variable has some common `base type` you have to make `virtual distructor` in derived types (just add `virtual` keywod in every destructor)

Comment: If I guess right, you are using UaModeler to generate the C++ code. I would suggest contacting Unified Automation support for details on the generated code. Their public forum is available at http://forum.unified-automation.com

Comment: already done, they won't generate destructors...

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is templating.

Let's define a generic templated function that works for any types

```
template <typename BaseDomainType_T, unsigned int PrefixID>
void deleteObject(unsigned int ObjID) {
  if (ObjID == PrefixID)
   {
      NodeManagerRoot* pNodeManagerRoot = NodeManagerRoot::CreateRootNodeManager();
      auto dummyTypeInstance = new BaseDomainType_T(UaNodeId(PrefixID, 2),
      UaString("Dummy_AutomationDomainType"), 2, pNodeManagerRoot);
      delete dummyTypeInstance;
   }
}
```

Let's define some dummy types to use. These are your generated types

```
typedef int BaseTypeOne;
typedef unsigned int BaseTypeTwo;
```

Use the templated function with every combination we have

```
void deleteObjectTypeUA(unsigned int ObjID, unsigned int NsIdx) {
    //For base type 1
    deleteObject<BaseTypeOne, 0>(ObjID);
    deleteObject<BaseTypeOne, 1>(ObjID);
    deleteObject<BaseTypeOne, 2>(ObjID);
    deleteObject<BaseTypeOne, 3>(ObjID);
    //For base type 2
    deleteObject<BaseTypeTwo, 0>(ObjID);
    deleteObject<BaseTypeTwo, 1>(ObjID);
}
```

Comment: If I understand it correctly, I'll have call the template-Function with all various BaseTypes in deleteObjectTypeUA. But i dont want to type in all possibilites of the 400 BaseTypes in deleteObjectTypeUA. I want to extract the choice, which BaseType to create, only from the Information of the ObjID, which is a int but defined as String-Macros.

Comment: I think I understand now. There is now way to do it I think. Since preprocessing replace the macros by their content before compiling.

If you want to do association, you have to declare it somewhere anyway.